# GraphQL - define a schema and query with default return fields

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

Is there a way to define a schema or query with default return fields?

I would like to returm certain fields when no fields are requested.
Is there a way to return all fields from the source (maybe using *)

Comment: You mean querying for data and not declaring the requested returned fields?

Comment: yes. Declaring in the schema. Not in the the request.

Comment: What would be a valid use case for this? Part of GraphQL's idea is to let the client decide what to include in the query and what to leave out, so without a valid use case this seems to partly defeat the purpose of GraphQL.

Answer (score 1):

So, I've been trying to play with the Schema, the returned GraphQLObjectType and the resolver of it and couldn't find a practical way to achieve what you were looking for.

What i ended up with was defining was defining an extra general field that **will be requested** by the query

something like :

```
{
    people{
         generic
    }
}
```

when `generic`'s resolver just returns an object containing all of the type's fields..

While this does not meet what you were looking for, this is what I was able to come up with after being unable to find an answer in google nor stack.

Would be glad to hear an alternative :)

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem, my solution was to use a middleware that adds to the client query requested fields (generic for example) before graphql perform query execution. Hope it helps